# How to calculate proper apkCertificateDigestSha256 having access to certificate?

Tags: android, safetynet

SafetyNet documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation) states that field returned in attestation token called apkCertificateDigestSha256 is `Base-64 encoded representation(s) of the SHA-256 hash of the calling app's signing certificate(s)`.

I might be misunderstanding what it means, since my data doesn't match. If I investigate my certificate fingerprints I have field SHA256, which has 32 bytes of length. When I try to encode it in base64 I get even longer string. This is sample result made with string `hello world` sha256 hashed and then encoded to base64:
`Yjk0ZDI3Yjk5MzRkM2UwOGE1MmU1MmQ3ZGE3ZGFiZmFjNDg0ZWZlMzdhNTM4MGVlOTA4OGY3YWNlMmVmY2RlOQ==`

Meanwhile google attestation token returns much shorter hashes that decoded from base64 show seemingly random values. For example this:
`EmGH9u67SiSyLuvZCoAN+R+NU/yHP29gSmoUgvNtehk=`
Which is nothing sensible after decoding.

How do I get to the same results as google gets based on my certificate? Why is their sha256 hash not 32 bytes long?

Comment: Did you perhaps base64-encode the text representation of the fingerprint rather than the binary data?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly that.

Comment: @Areinu can you please share the final code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As by Michael's suggestion in the comments the problem was I was using text representation of the fingerprint instead of binary data. By changing this one detail I managed to get the same results as Google returns.

Comment: Dint get what you are saing. can you share your code. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68046717/4450098

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to easily generate it
OSX:
`keytool -printcert -jarfile ~/PATH_TO/YOURAPKFILE.apk | grep "SHA256: " | cut -d " " -f 3 | xxd -r -p | openssl base64`

or if you already have a text representation of SHA256 signature the use this command
`echo "SHA256_TEXT_REPRESENTATION" | xxd -r -p | openssl base64`

xxd does a hex dump of input, basically text to binary